# Map Reduce Job in Apache Hadoop 2.0

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am following [Michael Noll](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python/) tutorial for setting up Multi-Node cluster and running a sample MapReduce Program. I am setting up Hadoop version 2.2.0. There is no **contrib** directory in Hadoop 2.2.0. I searched for jars using find command from the current directory. 
The search result was

[image]

My Question is **How to run a mapreduce program in Hadoop Multi-Node Cluster Environment ?**

Comment: were you able to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

Running MapReduce program on multinode cluster is same as Single node. steps for running sample mapreduce program for 0.23 and above(even for 2.2.0) is given in link:[Learnig hadoop](http://learninghadoopblog.wordpress.com/2013/08/03/hadoop-0-23-9-single-node-setup-on-ubuntu-13-04/).
Here Wordcount program is given. even u can run pi-estimator with the same jar

Answer (score 0):

We have a 4-node hadoop-2.2.0 cluster.

Able to run the wordcount test from command line by the following from the hadoop root folder (/usr/local/hadoop in our case) using:

```
hadoop jar share/hadoop/mapreduce/hadoop-mapreduce-examples-2.2.0.jar wordcount /user/
hduser/in /user/hduser/out
```

Note:

```
- folder name is different under hadoop: /share/hadoop/mapreduce/
```

We created the hduser/in folder (hdfs dfs -mkdir -p /user/hduser/in), copied a wordcount test file to it (hdfs dfs -copyFromLocal wc_test.txt /user/hduser/in) and specified an output folder (should not exist).